# Mini table of contents links does not work

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

The little hand that appears in my screenshot does not work in my document the same way. It only works when you place the little hands over the numbers. How can I fix it?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,      
        urlcolor=blue,
        citecolor=red,
        linktoc=page
        %pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{This is the first chapter}

{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\minitoc
}

\section{section}
This is a citation~\cite{ref1}. Theorem~\ref{thm1} provides some interesting information.
\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
    Rain gets you wet.
\end{theorem}
\section{section}
\section{section}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{thebibliography}{Smi19}

    \bibitem[Smi19]{ref1}
    John Smith.
    \newblock Citing in red.
    \newblock {\em Journal of Hyperlink Colors}, 2019.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to comment `linktoc=page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, `link` came for page numbers in `MiniTOC`, if you need the link for text, then please remove the tag `linktoc=page` from your setup (as already this was advised by `flav`)